# GWT Request Factory - Several entity locators for the same entity type

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

I want to be able to use different entity locators for the same domain object. I use `Twig` and it has an option to load an object fully or partially. When I run the lite request `fetchRangeLite`, the locator `TwigLocator` is used instead of `TwigLiteLocator`. My current implementation is:

Proxies

```
@ProxyFor(value = MyDomain.class, locator = TwigLocator.class)
public interface MyDomainProxy extends EntityProxy {}

@ProxyFor(value = MyDomain.class, locator = TwigLiteLocator.class)
public interface MyDomainLiteProxy extends EntityProxy {}
```

Request

```
@Service(value = MyDao.class, locator = DaoServiceLocator.class)
public interface MyRequest extends RequestContext {
    Request<List<MyDomainProxy>> fetchRange(Integer start, Integer length);
    Request<Integer> getCount();
    Request<List<MyDomainLiteProxy>> fetchRangeLite(Integer start, Integer length);
}
```

DAO

```
public List<MyDomain> fetchRange(Integer start, Integer length) {
  ...   
}

public List<MyDomain> fetchRangeLite(Integer start, Integer length) {
  ...   
}
```

**I was expecting the lite locator to be used but it's not the case. So how does RF choose which locator it should use for a specific domain type?**

**UPDATE**

My domain object is composed by list of lists.

```
public class MyDomain extends DatastoreObject {
  private List<A> a;
}

public class A {
  private List<B> b;
}
```

When a proxy of my `MyDomain` object is sent from the server to the client, `Twig` also loads all the `A`'s and all the `B`'s which takes time. I am only interested by a property in the `MyDomain` object, that's why I want to use a "lite" locator.

TwigLocator

```
@Override
public DatastoreObject find(Class< ? extends DatastoreObject> clazz, Long id) {
    ObjectDatastore myDatastore = datastoreProvider.get();
    DatastoreObject object = myDatastore.load(clazz, id);
    return object;
}
```

TwigLiteLocator

```
@Override
public DatastoreObject find(Class< ? extends DatastoreObject> clazz, Long id) {
    ObjectDatastore myDatastore = datastoreProvider.get();
    myDatastore.setActivationDepth(0);
    DatastoreObject object = myDatastore.load(clazz, id);
    return object;
}
```

`myDatastore.setActivationDepth(0);` tells the datastore to load only the properties in `MyDomain` and not the sublevel (List) properties.

The DAO implementation is the same, so the ID and version are the same for both proxies.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why RF isn't using the "lite" locator, but I'm not sure why it could be an issue either: shouldn't the ID and version be the same for MyDomain whichever the proxy being used?

Actually, I don't understand why you do need two different locators in this case: the "complete" or "lite" fetches are done in your DAO, not in the locators. The only reason for having two distinct locators would be to implement `find` differently, when a proxy is sent *from the client to the server* (`find` is also used by the default implementation of `isLive` but it's generally a good idea to override it with your own implementation, unless the default one is already the "best optimized" one: `find(obj.getClass(), getId(obj)) != null`)

Comment: See Update, also when is `find` method called? Is it only when a proxy is sent from the client to the server, or is it also called when a proxy is sent from the server to the client?

Comment: `find` is only called by the default implementation of `isLive` when you send from server to client. `isLive` is called for all entities seen in a given call (client-to-server and server-to-client). `find` will be called directly when sending from client to server to get the object to apply the "diff" to (because RF only sends diffs over the wire for client-to-server communications).

Comment: How does it work for `ValueProxy`? It seems that the locator is not called at all. I would lose the "diff" feature but I don't care since I am working with partially loaded object. BTW I am using the proxies in a `CellBrowser` that's why at the higher level I don't need all the information.

Comment: For `ValueProxy`s, only the `create` method of a `Locator` is ever called: there's no ID or version, so no need for `find` and `isLive` either. And `getDomainType` is actually never ever called (even for an `EntityProxy`).